# How to define an object with different type of value correctly in Typescript

Tags: typescript

**Goal**

I want to iterate through an array containing multiple objects, where each object is defined as following;

```
interface Todo {
    id: number;
    text:string;
    complete:boolean;
}
```

The function `findIndex(array: Todo[], attr:string, value: number | string | boolean)` iterate through array and check if array's element has the same value as the given value at the given attribute.

```
const findIndex = (array: Todo[], attr: string, value: number | string | boolean)=>{
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i][attr] === value) {
          return i;
        }
      }
    return -1;
}
```

**Problem**

However, the linter prompts error message, saying

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Todo'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Todo'.ts(7053)
```

**Tried**

I'm a newbie in typescript. I read through the documents of typescript, but the object in the explanation's code always come with same type of value for every properties. However, in my case, the value has various types, such as number, string, and boolean in a single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `keyof` operator:

```
interface Todo {
    id: number;
    text:string;
    complete:boolean;
}

const findIndex = (array: Todo[], attr: keyof Todo, value: number | string | boolean)=>{
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i][attr] === value) {
          return i;
        }
      }
    return -1;
}
```

`keyof` tells TS that `attr` will be one of `id`, `text` and `complete`.

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsAm7kG8BQyRywmAXMiAK4C2ARtANyHGQAeYZAzmFKAObNiyBOhoAHADYRIZOunTS4IZgF98+USB7IYoTAEkQmCG2QBeZAAo4UKHACeFDNgDaAXQA0yOGF4UAawgHdBg0LHRvADc4SSoICmp6aGQAH2QePhB+NOR5RQhlAEpzAD4CYRh0KCsYqBJzAAZGEgAeW3sHADppbLAACxbgAGphorwWYSJgGBs7R1dgd1dfXncLc0sYuIhxiqnhKBkqKBASIQPkdQPr4iOwE7OAWgBGNSA)